# Automatically add Github Issues to Github Project

Tags: github, automation, github-issues, github-projects

My github repository contains an ISSUE_TEMPLATE that helps users to create issues.
Also, I have a backlog where I'd like to track issues and automate that they appear as soon as new issues have been created.

[image]
[image]

The only missing link is that new issues are not automatically added to this backlog. I know how to do this manually after they have been created:

[image]

but there must be a way to assign the Project to it automatically!
I cannot find anything about it in Github's documentation though....https://docs.github.com/en/communities/using-templates-to-encourage-useful-issues-and-pull-requests/configuring-issue-templates-for-your-repository

Comment: As of now, I don't know how to autosize this but you can use the drag and drop function in the Project board: https://docs.github.com/en/issues/organizing-your-work-with-project-boards/tracking-work-with-project-boards/adding-issues-and-pull-requests-to-a-project-board

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this in directly in the project you want to automatically add issues to as follows:

1. Go to the project on GitHub
2. Click the "..." button in the upper-right corner of the project to open the project menu
3. Click the "Workflows" item in the menu to load the project's workflow page
4. Click the "Auto-add to project" item in the list of "Default workflows" on the left to view your project's auto-add workflows
5. Click the "Edit" button in the upper-right corner of the workflow view to edit the workflow
6. Add filters to one or more repositories to determine which issues should be automatically added to the project (pictured below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this GitHub Action: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/assign-to-one-project